# What is the term release from reset

Tags: embedded, microchip

I'm learning some embedded stuffs and microchip. I encountered the term "release from reset". It said that the middleware should release the chip from reset. What is the meaning of that term? Thanks!

Comment: Some context such as a link to the text where you saw this phrase or the name of the publication would help.  As it stands it makes no sense; while a chip is held in reset, no code will be running, so I cannot see how any "middleware" (itself a vague and ill-defined phrase) can be involved in its "release" unless it is running on a different device.

Answer (score 4):

The term *"release from reset"* is not a software action, it refers to the de-assertion of the hardware reset signal (normally an external pin, but may also be asserted by internal circuitry such as watchdog or brown-out circuits).

Normally the hardware design of a system assures that the device is held in reset for a period after power-on until such time as the power supply and external clock sources are stable and within the working parameters.

As such the term *"the middleware should release the chip from reset"* only makes sense in the general case if the "middleware" concerned is running on some device other than that being held in reset, since while in reset, no code will be running.  The term "middleware" itself is ill-defined, and what it constitutes depends largely on context.